# createAbsoluteUrl does not work in console app

Tags: yii2

In Console app `createAbsoluteUrl` does not work. Do I need to change some setting in config file to made it work.

As per my understanding the request component is not available in Console app. So where do I specify the base URL.

I did not find anything on this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: use `\Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl('site/index');`

Comment: It gives me Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Please configure UrlMa
nager::scriptUrl correctly as you are running a console application.' exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are unable to create URL in console application while you will receive the following error:

> 'Please configure `UrlManager::scriptUrl` correctly as you are running a console application.'

To get rid of this message and work with `UrlManager`, in your `console.php` config file, add the following configuration:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'scriptUrl' => 'http://path/to'
]
```

Now, if you write the following lines in your console app:

```
echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createAbsoluteUrl('test/test');
echo "\n";
echo \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('test/test');
```

You will see the following output:

```
http://path/to?r=test%2Ftest
http://path/to?r=test%2Ftest
```

Comment: it seems that `console.php` doesn't exists in my project.I am using the yii2 advanced template.

Comment: the array "urlManager" must be added to "components" array in console.php file